# Swift XML Parsing In Background

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I am programming an iOS application in Swift 3 and I am parsing a very large XML file (103558 lines) and pulling all the information I need from it with Swift's built-in XMLParser (used to be called NSXMLParser) without any issues.

The main problem is that with my application, I need all of that information as soon as my application loads, therefore the UI locks up for 12 seconds for the parsing to finish (the parsing starts as soon as the first UI page loads).

After researching a lot online and on Apple's documentation, I wasn't able to find much other than some Objective-C code that I wasn't able to figure out how to use with Swift 3. My main question is, is there a way to use the XMLParser or some other parser in a background thread or asynchronously?

Thanks in advance.

Cole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only operation that you cannot perform on a background thread is an UI operation.

> NSXMLParser parses data synchronously on the thread that calls it

So if you call the NSXMLParser on a background thread, all parsing would happen on background thread.

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue",
                                            qos: .background,
                                            target: nil)
        backgroundQueue.async {
            //call to 'parse' function of XMLParser
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //pass parsing result to UI on main thread
            }
        }
```

While the xml is being parsed in background thread, you can continue to display activity indicator (on main thread) to user. This way your UI will not get locked up while your xml is being parsed.